# MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been working on a data query that will select a record from a table using the parameters given.

It's been working perfectly when it is used in localhost but it throws an error when uploaded and used in production site.

Please look at the error

```
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL
statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away.
The SQL statement executed was: SELECT id from MST_PERSON WHERE last_name =
'name' and first_name = 'name'  and middle_name = 'name'  and
birth_date = 'date' limit 1 '
```

I have tried increasing the wait_timeout of sql but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked all base reasons from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html ?

Comment: Check if your provider provides access to your errors log. If it does, try to find the error generated by this query (or by something you do immediatly before this query).

Comment: @Enrico Are you flooding the MySQL database within an loop? that could also by an reason looks like it because off the limit 1.. show us an table structure and an explain off the query..

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `my.cnf`.. 
In case of linux you need to use : `vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

add:

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

and `restart mysql`

Comment: He selects a single row with a single id. How can max_allow_packet possibly exceed? :)

Comment: Common gotcha: if your my.cnf file contains the default settings then max_allowed_packet may be re-defined far into the file, overwriting your new value back to the default.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problem in google , it said 
change my.cnf
wait_timeout=28800

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Changing wait_timeout is not a good solution. IF the connection times out, he needs to understand the reason why this happens. But we don't even know if the connection times out.

Comment: you are right, thanks for your adv ：） ， All reason with server gone away is in my link, maybe @Enrico will check it all ：）